# Modify access token's user(Token User) or running a process elevated in context of a Standard User

Tags: c++, windows, security, process, access-token

I am trying to implement a small privilege management application for my college. I am trying to elevate a process in the context of the standard user itself.  I have the admin user credentials. [Logonuser()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) api to login as admin user and obtain it's token. And then use [CreateProcessAsUser()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessasusera) or [CreateProcessWithToken()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithtokenw) with obtained token. But the problem here is that, though the create process has administrator privileges(elevated in another terms) it runs in the context of the admini user and hence does not have access to all network folders shared to the standard user. So I want to run the process in the context of the standard user but with privileges of admin user.

So I got to know about this [SetTokenInformation()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-settokeninformation) where I can change the TokenUser property of the token. So that the TokenUser alone will be changed to the standard user and all other privileges will remain same of that of the admin user.

```
struct STokenUser
{
    TOKEN_USER* tu;
    DWORD sizeOfToken;
};

STokenUser GetTokenUserFromToken(HANDLE tokenHandle)
{
    STokenUser tu;
    TOKEN_USER  *tokenUser = NULL;
    DWORD       tokenSize;
    DWORD       sidLength;

    GetTokenInformation(tokenHandle,
        TokenUser,
        tokenUser,
        0,
        &tokenSize);
    if(GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        std::cout << "GetTokenInformation failed with " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    tokenUser = (TOKEN_USER *)malloc(tokenSize);

    if (!GetTokenInformation(tokenHandle,
        TokenUser,
        tokenUser,
        tokenSize,
        &tokenSize))
    {
        free(tokenUser);
        std::cout << "GetTokenInformation failed with " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    tu.tu = tokenUser;
    tu.sizeOfToken = tokenSize;

    return tu;
}

auto tu = GetTokenUserFromToken(hToken);

tu.tu->User.Sid = psidOfTheStandardUser;

if(!SetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, &tu.tu, tu.sizeOfToken))
{
    std::cout << "SetTokenInformation fails with error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
}
```

I expected the process to run elevated in the context of the standard user. But SetTokenInformation failed with error code 87(meaning invalid parameters passed).

I don't know where I am failing. I have read somewhere that it is impossible to change TokenUser of a token.

How to fix this? or is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: It can't be done. You need to pass through UAC (with ShellExecute/run as). Even if a user belongs to the administrators group and you get a token using LogonUser(), this token is not elevated and cannot be elevated programmatically.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis, in that case the token is linked to the elevated admin token, and a user with SeTcbPrivilege can get the `TokenLinkedToken` as a primary token for use with `CreateProcessAsUser`. However, trying to elevate the token of a *standard user* in place isn't going to work, not completely, and no one is allowed to set `TokenUser` for an existing token. It's probably doable if a new token is created for the existing logon session via `NtCreateTokenEx`, after first impersonating the token from lsass.exe to get SeCreateTokenPrivilege.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, you are right. If the user is administrator then it is just simple matter of using GetTokenInformation to get linked token and then starting the process in the context of that token. What I am trying to achieve is more close to what you are saying later. Can you please elaborate that a bit as an answer? WIll be more than happy! Thank You!

Comment: @eryksun Assuming I have SeCreateTokenPrivilege as I am running as a system service, yet I still stuck with two parameters ` _In_ PLUID AuthenticationId, _In_ PLARGE_INTEGER ExpirationTime`. Will be very helpful if you can point me in the right direction how to obtain these two?